# Angular2 OIDC with systemjs

Tags: angular, oauth, openid-connect

I'm trying to load a library into an Angular2 application using systemjs to bootstrap it.

I have found these two libraries

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-oauth2
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc

But I'm having trouble to make it all work.

*systemjs.config.js* along with the other dependencies.

`map : { 'ng2-oauth2' : 'node_modules/ng2-oauth2/bundles/ng2-oauth2.js' }`

And I'm trying to import it like this, but it fails

`import {OAUTH2_PROVIDERS } from 'ng2-oauth2';`

So my questions,

1. Do you have any preference between these libraries ?
2. Am I doing the mapping wrong or these libraries weren't made for systemjs ?

I want to intergrate my application with Google OIDC as a test IdP and then my own.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular-oauth2-oidc, here is systemjs config

```
'angular-oauth2-oidc': {
   main: 'angular-oauth2-oidc.umd.js',
   format: 'cjs',
   defaultExtension: 'js',
   map: {
       'jsrsasign': '/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign',
   },
   meta: {
        'angular-oauth2-oidc': {
        deps: ['require','jsrsasign']
       },
  }
}
```

check [this](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/master/docs-src/systemjs.md) for more details